# non-member function begin()/cbegin() and its constexpr-ness

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

C++11 introduced `std::begin()` non-member function without `constexpr`-specifier, and then C++14 updates to constexpr-`std::begin()` for array type(`T (&)[N]`) and appends constexpr-`std::cbegin()` for generic container type(`const C&`).

Quote from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin

> ```
> template< class T, size_t N >
> constexpr T* begin( T (&array)[N] );  // (since C++14)
>
> template< class C >
> constexpr auto cbegin( const C& c ) -> decltype(std::begin(c));  // (since C++14)
> ```

So we can use `std::begin()` and/or `std::cbegin()` in constexpr context for raw array type `T[N]` (for C++14 constexpr function).

Question:

1. C++14 does NOT allow  non-member `std::begin()` in constexpr context for "Standard Containers" such as `std::array`, because they doesn't provide constexpr-`begin()` member function. Is my interpretation correct?
2. Why does non-member `std::cbegin()` have `constexpr`-specifier? For user provided container which have constexpr-`begin()` member function?

Comment: `std::cbegin` calls `std::begin`, which isn't `constexpr`...with two exceptions: [the `initializer_list` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin2) and the array one.

Comment: For question #2, if you removed it, you would no longer have `constexpr` for raw array `cbegin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current `constexpr` support in the Standard Library is indeed rather limited.

1. non-member `std::begin` is not marked `constexpr` because apart from `array` and `initializer-list`, no Standard Container (or container like entity such as `bitset`) supports `constexpr` member `begin()` (mainly because some implementations want to use iterator debugging using dynamic memory allocation). Your interpretation here is correct.
2. non-member `std::cbegin` is marked `constexpr` in order to support the (currently) two `constexpr` `std::begin` non-member functions for `array` and `initializer_list`, and to be forward-compatible for future upgrades in the Standard Library.

Regarding point 2., it is not so useful for user-defined container like entities, because there the accepted idiom is to define non-member `begin()` and `end()` in the namespace surrounding the user-defined type, and not in `namespace std`.